# Is it possible to embed a video in a powerpoint and then save the powerpoint as a video?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

Is it possible to embed a video in a powerpoint and then save the powerpoint as a video?

- The powerpoint should contain normal slides
- The powerpoint should contain multiple embedded videos
- The powerpoint should be saved as an MP4 video

If so how should I do it?

I embedded on file and saved it as a video, but it was not playing. I get the feeling that it should be possible and I am just doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.wikihow.com/Convert-Powerpoint-to-Mp4

for figuring out how to convert the finished product, this link will help. Before that, make sure that your video is set to play automatically when the slide is shown. You should be able to do that from the media tab that comes up when you click on the video. Once you do that, try to save the slides as a video and jump to the video you input. Then tell us what happens to the video inside the video slide so that we can help troubleshoot or bask in the glory of our victory.

Comment: Converting is not the problem, powerpoint has a save as video option. I'll try auto play.